# Два варианта авторизации в одном приложении, в разных окнах, через WebView

Tags: java, javafx, webview

Столкнулся с проблемой при использовании компонента WebView и WebEngine .
есть 2 кнопки

```
    @FXML
    Button bt1;

    @FXML
    Button bt2;


    public void bt1_click(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {
        PostLP.login = "логин1";
        PostLP.password = "пароль1";
        Application ap = new Boiler_control();
        ap.start(new Stage());
   }


    public void bt2_click(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws Exception {
        PostLP.login = "логин2";
        PostLP.password = "пароль2";
        Application ap = new Boiler_control();
        ap.start(new Stage());
    }
```

соответственно вот код самого класса Boiler_control

```
package boilercontrolpanel;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Boiler_control extends Application {

    public enum Status {
        login_request,
        control_request,
    }

    Status status = Status.login_request;

    String setLogin = "document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value='" + PostLP.login + "';";
    String setPassword = "document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value='" + PostLP.password + "';";
    String btnLogin = "document.getElementById('btnLogin').click();";



    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("boiler_control.fxml"));

        WebView webView = (WebView) root.lookup("#web_view");
        webView.setVisible(true);
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine

        webEngine.load("https://сайт");

        Label label = (Label) root.lookup("#label");

        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) root.lookup("#prbar");

        progressBar.progressProperty().bind(webEngine.getLoadWorker().progressProperty());

        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
                new ChangeListener<State>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                        if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                            // Если страница загрузилась то
                            if (status == Status.control_request) {
                                progressBar.setVisible(false);
                                webView.setVisible(true);
                            }

                            if (status == Status.login_request) {
                                // Авторизуемся
                                label.setText("Загрузка интерфейса управления горелкой");
                                login(webEngine);
                                status = Status.control_request;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                });

        primaryStage.setTitle("Консоль управления котельной");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 900, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void login(WebEngine webEngine) {
        webEngine.executeScript(setLogin);
        webEngine.executeScript(setPassword);
        webEngine.executeScript(btnLogin);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

При нажатии одной из кнопок мы изначально попадаем на дефолтную страницу авторизации и всё проходит хорошо, но если закрыть окно и нажать на 2ю кнопку то хотя окна совершенно разные и компоненты WebView разные, но во вновь созданном окне отображается страница с уже авторизованным пользователем.

Вопрос почему это происходит ? неужели WebEngine является общим для всех экземпляров WebView текущего приложения. И как мне сделать чтобы в разных окнах был свой пользователь (как будто бы открыты разные браузеры ?)

Comment: добавьте в вопрос [mcve]. текущий код содержит ошибки.

Comment: 1й листинг это часть кода контроллера, в котором реализованы реакции на нажатия кнопок. 2й листинг это класс наследующий Application который в свою очередь создаёт отдельное окно с WebView , через статичные поля PostLP я передаю логин и пароль для авторизации новому экземпляру класса  Boiler_control. Думаю этого описания более чем достаточно для понимания сути, зачем постить весь исходный код.

Comment: потому, что запустить этот код нельзя. а описанное поведение выглядит странным.

Comment: мммм, я не могу привести полный листинг программы. т.к. без логинов и паролей он не имеет смысла, т.к. только после того как пройдена авторизация начинается свистопляска. Я частично решил проблему очисткой куков в рамках текущей сессии. Но вопрос еще актуален . И если уж совсем отойти от моего кода то сводится он к тому как к примеру запустить в 2х окнах к примеру 2 разные авторизованные страницы Вконтакте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На англоязычном SO есть  [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23470976/3452146) по данной теме.

Суть состоит в том, что куки для WebView хранятся в `java.net.CookieHandler`.

Чтобы управлять куками самостоятельно, необходимо создать инстан `java.net.CookieManager` и проставить его как дефолтый:

```
java.net.CookieManager manager = new java.net.CookieManager();
java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);
```

Чтобы очистить куки, необходимо вызвать метод `removeAll()` или же создать новый инстанс `CookieManager` и проставить его как дефолтный :

```
manager.getCookieStore().removeAll();

//or

java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(new java.net.CookieManager());
```